# parsing JSON file (URL) with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

since I'm trying this for about 10 hours now I would appreciate any solution.
I need a speciffic value of a JSON but have no Idea how to select it.

So this is my JSON

```
    {
    "results" : [
        {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "Buchenberg",
           "short_name" : "Buchenberg",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Oberallgäu",
           "short_name" : "Oberallgäu",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Swabia",
           "short_name" : "Swabia",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Bavaria",
           "short_name" : "BY",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Germany",
           "short_name" : "DE",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Buchenberg, Germany",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 47.7525249,
              "lng" : 10.286058
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 47.6694625,
              "lng" : 10.1128175
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 47.6960163,
           "lng" : 10.239696
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 47.7525249,
              "lng" : 10.286058
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 47.6694625,
              "lng" : 10.1128175
           }
        }
     },
     "place_id" : "ChIJA6IwOqmAm0cRxVEUeHkZnrg",
     "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
    }
  ],
  "status" : "OK"
}
```

I need to get the data of lat/lng from formatted address->geometry->bounds->northeast.

I tried this JS code

```
     $.getJSON("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=buchenberg", function(result){
         var geoArray = result;
         alert(geoArray['status']);     
     });
```

and it returns "OK", like it's supposed to.
But how how can I select the lat/lng since it's involved so deep into this array and all this brackets :D pls help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your url returns results inside an array, at index 0, so you will need to access that first, to access the properties of the geometry object

```
    var lat = geoArray.results[0].geometry.bounds.northeast.lat;
    var long = geoArray.results[0].geometry.bounds.northeast.lng;
```

```js
var result =   {
    "results" : [
        {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "Buchenberg",
           "short_name" : "Buchenberg",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Oberallgäu",
           "short_name" : "Oberallgäu",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Swabia",
           "short_name" : "Swabia",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Bavaria",
           "short_name" : "BY",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Germany",
           "short_name" : "DE",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Buchenberg, Germany",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 47.7525249,
              "lng" : 10.286058
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 47.6694625,
              "lng" : 10.1128175
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 47.6960163,
           "lng" : 10.239696
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 47.7525249,
              "lng" : 10.286058
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 47.6694625,
              "lng" : 10.1128175
           }
        }
     },
     "place_id" : "ChIJA6IwOqmAm0cRxVEUeHkZnrg",
     "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
    }
  ],
  "status" : "OK"
};
var geoArray = result;
var lat = geoArray.results[0].geometry.bounds.northeast.lat;
var long = geoArray.results[0].geometry.bounds.northeast.lng;

console.log(lat);
console.log(long);
```

output:

```
  lat  47.7525249
  long  10.286058
```

Comment: you can look for json selectors (where you can paste the object and select properties by clicking on them) which might help point you in the right direction faster if you have large/confusing objects

Comment: You should change the name "geoArray" into "results" i think. Or the other way around.

Comment: @user2950720 just had a look at a json selector (http://jsonselector.com/), that's really awesome, thanks for that info!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will work :**

```
 // Latitude.
 var lat = Obj.results[0].geometry.bounds.northeast.lat;
 // Longitude.
 var lng = Obj.results[0].geometry.bounds.northeast.lng;
```

**Print in console :**

```
console.log(lat);
console.log(lng);
```

**JsFiddle :** https://jsfiddle.net/n7voyo6t/

Answer (score -1):

The below code will extract the lat/long from the northeast key within the bounds object.

```
 alert(geoArray[0].geometry.bounds.northeast);
```

Also, you could write it like this:

```
 alert(geoArray[0]['geometry']['bounds']['northeast']);
```